# Can't figure out how to get rid of syntax error on mysql

Tags: java, mysql, database, intellij-idea

I'm trying to run a statement on the java main file and I'm able to connect to the data base, but not run the sql statement
my code is:

```
try {
            System.out.println("Connecting to the database...");
            conn=DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);
            System.out.println("Connected to database successfully");
            System.out.println("Inserting");
            stmt=conn.createStatement();
            String sql="USE TheEmployeeDatabase" +
                    "SELECT * FROM EmployeeTable";
            stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
            System.out.println("worked");
        }  catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

and getting the error

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax
```

Comment: If you printed the value of String `sql` or examined it in a debugger, you would see that you have fused the database name with the `SELECT` keyword.

Comment: Furthermore, do note that it is conventional to specify the database in the JDBC URL, as opposed to via a `USE` statement.  Also, I suspect -- but have not verified -- that the `USE` needs to be a separate statement, not a modifier to a `SELECT` statement.  In that case, you'll at least need a semicolon between the two statements.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I have the JBDC URL. Where would I put it in the statement?

Comment: You don't put the JDBC URL in the statement. Can you include your JDBC URL (without any private info) in your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as the schema name `TheEmployeeDatabase1` is part of your `DB_URL`, you don't need to have the `USE TheEmployeeDatabase` statement.

You statement should just be:

```
SELECT * FROM EmployeeTable
```

Comment: Thank you so much. How would you output the results?

Comment: You are using `executeUpdate`. This is used when you want to insert, update or delete something in the database. When you want to select something, you should use `executeQuery` which will return you a `ResultSet`. Read the Java docs about `Statement` and `ResultSet`.

Answer (score 0):

String sql="USE TheEmployeeDatabase " <--- you need whitespace here or you will have TheEmployeeDatabaseSELECT concatenated

Comment: `USE TheEmployeeDatabase SELECT * FROM EmployeeTable` is not a valid SQL statement either.

Comment: how do you display the results for the select statement